# JSON schema to validate that property name matches nested value

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema, ajv

We are using JSON to store some configuration settings. For example:

```
{
  "source1": {
    "name": "source1",
    "standalone": false
  },
  "source2": {
    "name": "source2",
    "standalone": true
  },
  "source3": {
    "name": "source3",
    "standalone": true
  }
}
```

As you can see, the source names are variable and are repeated for convenience inside the object under a property `name`.

We're currently validating this using a JSON schema as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^\\w[-\\w_]*$": { "$ref": "#/definitions/source" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "source": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "standalone": { "type": "boolean" }
      },
      "required": ["name", "standalone"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to require that the property name matches the value using JSON schema? In other words, is there a way to make sure the following example fails to validate?

```
{
  "a": {
    "name": "b",
    "standalone": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you reference other property values in JSON schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997246/how-do-you-reference-other-property-values-in-json-schema)

Comment: Sorry. This is not currently possible! However, this does give me an idea on how we COULD do this in future. I'll table my idea with the rest of the spec group.