# Looking for a possibility to depending on min/max values in a JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a JSON schema (draft 4), which could have min and max values optionally.

Is there a way to check in the schema, if both values are set, that minimum is lower then max?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "minDuration": {
            "description": "The required minimum duration in seconds",
            "type": [
                "integer",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "maxDuration": {
            "description": "The maximum duration, which should not exceeded",
            "type": [
                "integer",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: I've posted an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64849532/545550